# Is it correct to say "CMP command is the longest assembly command"?

Tags: assembly

In compare with other assembly statement like JMP, CALL, MOV, PUSH (I mean more usable commands) is it correct to say CMP take more time to run?

Comment: Um... where did you hear that from?

Comment: please specify the instruction set architecture (processor) you are talking about.  jumps can lead to flushing the pipe which is more expensive than a compare which is about the simplest alu command (a sub that you dont have to save the answer.  Push causes a memory access (or more) which can be slow.  What do you mean by more usable commands the cmp command is not a rarely used instruction.

Comment: A task-switching `iret` is way more expensive than `cmp` on x86...

Answer (score 0):

no, MOV by far can take the longest to run because generically speaking it has to hit memory to perform the move (much slower than register access), and can be blocking. CMP on the other hand generically takes literals and registers as arguments in practice and only hits the ALU.

CALL actually does a PUSH and a JUMP so is the second longest. Oh yes, and as mentioned, JMP can flush the pipeline (although an unconditional jump would not).

Bottom line CMP is fast, fast like INC, ADD, or any other simple math calc that more often than not is optimized to use register values and literals, and doesn't do anything more than hit the ALU.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Indeed, I'm C++ programmer and always i try to keep my codes clean. Something in my mind always tell me avoid if! anyway you answer was so useful.

Comment: By frequency, CPUs spend most of their time doing "LOAD", "CMP", "JMP".  Your processor wouldn't be fast unless the architects tuned these instructions for maximal performance... and they did. CMP is fast.